# Drawing a frame around an image inside a minipage in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I use the following code to draw a frame around an image inside a minipage. How can it be set globally, and how to control frame line thickness and colour individually.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
 \frametitle{}
 \lineskip=-\fboxrule
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}
{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{x.PNG}
\end{minipage}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you would use any of the example images from the `mwe` package, people could actually compile your example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the value of `\fboxrule` in a usual way. To change the color, you can use the `\fcolorbox`.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mwe}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{5pt}
\def\myfbox#1{%
    \lineskip=-\fboxrule
    \fcolorbox{cyan}{white}{%
        \begin{minipage}
        {\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}
        \end{minipage}%
        }%
    }%


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\myfbox{example-image-a}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\myfbox{example-image-b}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\myfbox{example-image-c}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\myfbox{example-image}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer to set the frame colour. But the (frame setting code) should be repeated for every image. I would like to set it once as a style, for example, then apply it for every image without repeating the whole code.

Comment: @Hany: See my edited answer. I defined the command `\myfbox` that does the job. If you want to change the box color, rewrite the corresponding part in the definition (now, the color is set to `cyan`). For changing line thickness, set the value `\fboxrule` that fits your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one modification please; can the colour and the graphic text width in (\includegraphics[width=xx\textwidth) be set as parameters as well.

Comment: Yes, surely. Simply rewrite the command mask to `\def\myfbox#1#2#3` (e.g., #1 - color specification, #2 - width specification, #3 - filename of the picture). However, then you need to specify all three arguments every time `\myfbox` is used. And this has nothing to do with the global specification of color you mentioned in your original question.

Comment: Thank you Marian very much. That is what I need. By global I meant not having to rewrite the whole code for each image. But each image has its own dimensions which needs to redefine its own textwidth; and its colour components which need to redefine its own frame colour. But these do not interfere with the "global setting". So, thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with `tcbincludegraphics` (from `tcolorbox`)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
 \frametitle{Default}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
 \frametitle{Version 1}
\tcbincludegraphics[sharp corners, colback=white]{example-image-a}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
 \frametitle{Version 2}
\tcbincludegraphics[sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=blue, boxrule=2mm,
hbox, graphics options={width=.25\linewidth}, left=2cm, right=2cm]{example-image-a}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]